# What is the Joule-Thomson measurements uncertainty?

Tags: thermodynamics, measurements

I will be measuring the Joule-Thomson coefficient for noble gases and I am trying to perform the uncertainty budget analysis prior to the measurements. However, I have my doubts here.

The JT coefficient is

$$\mu_{\rm JT} = \left. \frac{\partial T}{\partial p} \right|_{\rm h}.$$

The combined expanded uncertainty is defined as

$$U_{\rm c} = k \sqrt{\sum^N_{i=1} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 U^2(x_i)},$$

where $f$ is the JT coefficient in my case; $x_i$ is the measured property ($T_{\rm in}$, $T_{\rm out}$, $p_{\rm in}$, $p_{\rm out}$), $U$ is the single measurement uncertainty, $k$ is the coverage factor and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ is the sensitivity coefficient of the measurement $x_i$.

The conditions will be kept constant at the entrance to the $\Delta p$ imposing medium and will vary at the outlet, thanks to which I will follow the isenthalp and measure the integrated JT coefficient for each isenthalp from which I will later obtain the actual, local JT coefficients.

The question is: how to actually calculate the combined expanded uncertainty?

$$U_{\rm c} = k \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial \mu_{\rm JT}}{\partial T_{\rm in}}\right)^2 U^2(T_{\rm in}) + \left(\frac{\partial \mu_{\rm JT}}{\partial T_{\rm out}}\right)^2 U^2(T_{\rm out}) + \left(\frac{\partial \mu_{\rm JT}}{\partial p_{\rm in}}\right)^2 U^2(p_{\rm in}) + \left(\frac{\partial \mu_{\rm JT}}{\partial p_{\rm out}}\right)^2 U^2(p_{\rm out})}$$

What is the significance of the following and how to calculate the sensitivity coefficients, e.g.,
$$\frac{\partial \mu_{\rm JT}}{\partial T_{\rm in}} = \frac{\partial \frac{\partial T}{\partial p}}{\partial T_{\rm in}}$$

I may be wrong in my understanding here so any thoughts are appreciated!